# I was making an app when this came up, "Installed Build Tools revision 29.0.3 is corrupted"

Tags: android, helper, android-sdk-manager, build-tools

I need to fix this app. I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Installed Build Tools revision 29.0.3 is corrupted.
Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.
```

Now its saying

```
Module 'app': platform 'android-29' not found.
```

Comment: What happened when you took the advice in the error?

Comment: I installed the SDK Manager it still doesn't work

Comment: I wonder if it wants you to remove and reinstall Build Tools?